# How to set active link in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set active link when user clik on it but i cant figureout how to remove last clicked.
This is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9ff79/222/

```
 $(function() {
  $( 'nav ul li a' ).on( 'click', function() {
        $(this).parent().find( 'nav ul li a .active' ).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

});

Comment: ? http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/9ff79/223/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM traversal from the clicked `a` element isn't correct. Use `closest()` then `find()` to get the current `.active` element:

```
$('nav ul li a').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('nav ul').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ff79/224/)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got there:

```
$(function() {
      $('nav ul li a').on('click', function() {
            $('nav ul li a').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from ALL href's
            $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class for the element clicked
      });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/9ff79/223/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have more nav-elements you a and .active. That is implying you have a child element with the class active.

Try this:

```
$( 'nav ul li a.active' ).removeClass('active');
```